# Get multiple child values from Firebase real time database using single callback

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I have this type of structure in my firebase real time db. I want to fetch multiple child's last item's data for only once.

I am following below approach :

```
for (roomId in roomInformation.keys) { 

// roomInformation will contain some of room ids 
// to fetch from firebase db(not all roomIds from Messages)
    
    val messageObserver = object : ValueEventListener {
    ...
    }
    
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                .child("Messages")
                .child(roomId)
                .limitToLast(1)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(messageObserver)
    
}
```

I don't want to fetch all `childs (roomIds)` from `Messages` Collection. This looping approach to get data from firebase is working but I want to fetch required records in a single callback **(without for loop)**. Is there any possibility to do this or Is there any other better approach for same?

**UPDATE**:
More clarification:

As per image: there is one Messages collection which include id's of Rooms and inside that rooms there are thousands of messages. I want to fetch all room's last message. So as per query I applied: Messages -> RoomId -> limitToLast(1) so It will give me last message info of particular room.
User might join with hundreds of rooms and initially when user do login I want to display all rooms last message. so I am fetching messages of rooms by using **for loop** so Firebase will give me a single room last message at a time but I want all rooms last messages at a time.
Here all room in the sense, **Messages** Collection is having 300 Rooms and If **UserA** is joined with **50 rooms** then I only wants last messages of **50 rooms**

Comment: Can you make it more clear by adding for database screenshots and also the reason for not wanting to make use of loop . Also some more information about the logic that you are using can be helpful .

Comment: Hey Nik. To understand better. Do you want to get all objects that exist within the Messages node? Meaning two-level deep in the node?

Comment: @KARUNESHPALEKAR  - added more clarification. Reason not to make for loop -> To minimize Firebase call and reduce time to fetch data

Answer (score 1):

Firebase queries function on a flat list of nodes, so they can't query across all rooms that you have under `/Messages` in one go. But firing multiple queries is not as slow as many developers think, as Firebase [pipelines the requests over a single web socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).

If you don't want to make multiple calls, the solution is to add an additional data structure that has exactly what you need. For example, it is quite common for a chat app on Firebase to have a top-level node:

```
"latestMessagePerRoom": {
  "theSameRoomIdYouAlreadyHave": {
    "timestamp": 1604488509642,
    "message": ...
    ...
  }
}
```

So whenever you `push()` a message to a chat room, you also `set` it to this location. You'll end up with some duplicate data, but now your use-case of showing the latest message for all rooms becomes trivial to implement.

This is a common trade-off when working with NoSQL databases, and my common recommendation is to make your data model closely reflect what you're showing on your screen. So here: if you're showing a list with the latest message for each chat room, that's also what we're storing in the database.

For some more guidance on such data modeling consideration, I recommend checking out [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and David East's excellent [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) video series.